# create a large arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

could someone please explain to me how to create a large arraylist of objects currently, this is what i have.

public ArrayList particlecollection;

```
public ParticleColl(Particle thorium)
{
    particlecollection = new ArrayList<Particle>();

    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        particlecollection.add("Thorium",24.07);
    }
    System.out.println(particlecollection.get(3));
}
```

The particlecollection.add("Thorium",24.07) is referring to a Particle class, which has 2 paramaters

Particle(String name, double halflife)

The error that I am being given is "cannot find symbol- method add(java.lang.string,double);  maybe you meant add(Particle) or add(int,Particle).

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That hasn't anything to do with the size of the array list.  You forgot to construct your `Particle` object.

```
particlecollection.add(new Particle("Thorium",24.07));
```

Or quite possibly what you want is

```
particlecollection.add(thorium);
```

Comment: Oh thanks. Sorry, I'm relatively new to programming and still pretty nubby at it

Comment: Click the tick beside the answer.  It tells future readers of the question that this answer works.  So if they have the same issue, they know the solution

Comment: oh, i see, i have to wait 5 mins to do that

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList can only add the object of the class which be used when the ArrayList is declared.

```
particlecollection.add(new Particle("Thorium",24.07));
```